# Create Counter with Binary Variable

Tags: r, counter

I am trying to create a counter variable that starts over at 1 every time there is a change in a binary variable.

```
bin <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df <- as.data.frame(bin)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  mutate(cntr = row_number())
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
bin  cntr
1    1
0    1
0    2
1    1
1    2
1    3
...
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
1    1
0    1
0    2
1    2
1    3
1    4
```

I understand why this is ... I just don't know how to get my desired results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a `run-length-id` to group the adjacent same elements into a single group.  It can be done with `rleid` from `data.table` or create a logical index and then do the cumulative sum (`cumsum(bin != lag(bin, default = first(bin)))`)

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(bin))  %>% 
   mutate(cntr = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 16 x 2
#     bin  cntr
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     0     1
# 3     0     2
# 4     1     1
# 5     1     2
# 6     1     3
# 7     1     4
#..
```

---

In `data.table`, this can be done more compactly as the `:=` happens

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cntr := rowid(rleid(bin))]
df
#    bin cntr
# 1:   1    1
# 2:   0    1
# 3:   0    2
# 4:   1    1
# 5:   1    2
# 6:   1    3
# 7:   1    4
#..
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this by combining `sequence` and `rle`. No packages required.

```
data.frame(bin, cntr = sequence(rle(bin)$lengths))
#   bin cntr
#1    1    1
#2    0    1
#3    0    2
#4    1    1
#5    1    2
#6    1    3
#7    1    4
#8    1    5
#9    0    1
#10   0    2
#11   0    3
#12   0    4
#13   1    1
#14   0    1
#15   1    1
#16   0    1
```